# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ApellidoM', table 'name'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to save data in my database using Javascript but always receive the same error. Im using MVC and send data using axios
.NET has a form to access to my request data and manipulate as I want?
Model

```
public class Pensionado
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int No_activo { get; set; }
        public bool Cobro_indebido { get; set; }    
        [Required]
        public bool Status_pago { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Clave_pension { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int No_afiliado { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int No_pension { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool Sexo { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string ApellidoP { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string ApellidoM { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime Fecha_nacimiento { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(13)]
        [Required]
        public string RFC { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(18)]
        [Required]
        public string CURP { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }   
        public int Estado_civilId { get; set; } 
        public Estado_civil estado_Civil { get; set; }
        public int Tipo_PensionId { get; set; }
        public Tipo_Pension tipo_Pension { get; set; }
    }
```

I tried omitting FromBody but I received the same error

```
[HttpPost] 
public async Task<ActionResult<Pensionado>> Post([FromBody] Pensionado pensionado)
        {
            var usuarioId = servicesUsuario.ObtenerUsuarioId();
           var pensionadoBD = new Pensionado
            {
                No_activo = pensionado.No_activo,
                Cobro_indebido = pensionado.Cobro_indebido,
                Clave_pension = pensionado.Clave_pension,
                No_afiliado = pensionado.No_afiliado,
                No_pension = pensionado.No_pension,
                Sexo = pensionado.Sexo,
                ApellidoP = pensionado.ApellidoP,
                ApellidoM = pensionado.ApellidoM,
                Nombre = pensionado.Nombre,
                Fecha_nacimiento = pensionado.Fecha_nacimiento,
                RFC = pensionado.RFC,
                CURP = pensionado.CURP,
                Estado_civilId = pensionado.Estado_civilId,
                Tipo_PensionId = pensionado.Tipo_PensionId,
                Email = pensionado.Email
            };
            context.Add(pensionadoBD);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return pensionado;
        }
```

Javascript post function

```
export const guardarPensionado = async (url, data) => {
    return http.POST(url, data)
        .then((res => { }))
        .catch(error => {
            if (error.response) {
                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
            } else if (error.request) {

                console.log(error.request);
            } else {
                console.log('Error', error.message);
            }
            console.log(error.config);
            console.log(error)
            throw new Error('A ocurrido un error.', error)
        })
}
```

Index script where I call POST function

```
btnGuardar.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    try {
        const data = obtenerDatosFormulario()
        await guardarPensionado(UrlApiBase, data);
        alert('Se guardo al pensionado');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

});

//Return the data correctly
const obtenerDatosFormulario = () => { 
    return {
        No_activo: parseInt(formPensionado.no_activo.value),
        Status_pago: 0,
        Clave_pension: parseInt(formPensionado.clave_pension.value),
        No_afiliado: parseInt(formPensionado.no_afiliado.value),
        No_pension: parseInt(formPensionado.no_pension.value),
        Sexo: parseInt(d.querySelector('input[name=sexo]:checked').value) || 0,
        ApellidoP: formPensionado.apellidoP.value,
        ApellidoM: formPensionado.apellidoM.value,
        Nombre: formPensionado.nombre.value,
        Fecha_nacimiento: formPensionado.fecha_nacimiento.value,
        RFC: formPensionado.rfc.value,
        CURP: formPensionado.curp.value,
        Email: formPensionado.email.value,
        Estado_civilId: parseInt(formPensionado.estado_civil.value),
        Tipo_PensionId: parseInt(formPensionado.tipo_pensiones.value),
        Cobro_indebido: formPensionado.cobre_indebido.checked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Based on your comment, I think you are having a little mess while sending request. I have simulate your issue both in client side and Backend both worked as expected. here is the takeaways:

**When Submit As [FromBody]:**

Let's assume, you want to submit request from client-side as `[FromBody]` for instance,

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Pensionado>> Post([FromBody] Pensionado pensionado)
        {
           ... Your Code

        }
```

In above scenario, you should submit request as below:

```
         var data = {
                Id: 101,
                No_activo: 1,
                Cobro_indebido: true,
                ApellidoP: "Test P ",
                ApellidoM: "Test M ",
            }
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:5094/Controller/Post",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (res) {
                    alert(res)
                },
                error: function (res) {
                    alert(res)
                }
            });
```

**Note:** Importantly, when submit `[FromBody]` you must parse your data into `JSON.stringify()` and set content type explicitly likee `contentType: "application/json"` either of the violation will submit null data.

**When Submit As Class Parameter:**

```
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<ActionResult<Pensionado>> Post(Pensionado pensionado)
            {
               ... Your Code

            }
```

In above scenario, you do not need to parse your data explicitely into json like this way `JSON.stringify()`. However, in this case, you should submit request as below:

```
         var data = {
                Id: 101,
                No_activo: 1,
                Cobro_indebido: true,
                ApellidoP: "Test P ",
                ApellidoM: "Test M ",
            }
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:5094/EntityJoinRelationship/Post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: data,
                success: function (res) {
                    alert(res)
                },
                error: function (res) {
                    alert(res)
                }
            });
```

**Note:** You can notice, here `contentType: "application/json"` and `JSON.stringify()` not required. You just need to pass data as  `data: data,` as your value comes.

**Output:**

[image]

> I tried omitting FromBody but I received the same error

Well, the issue is not within your`FromBody`, it's in your `Pensionado` class. If you would like to allow `null` for column `ApellidoM`, then you need to get rid of the `[Required]` annotation from its definition. Assign additional `?` like `string?` to it which tells this property to accept null value.

It should as below:

```
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string? ApellidoM { get; set; }
```

**Note:** you should bear in mind that [`[Required]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#required-and-optional-properties) makes your table schema `non-nullable` by setting it `not null`. You can get more detail in the [`official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#required-and-optional-properties).

Comment: String is a reference type and always nullable, the `?` is only needed for value type.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm not explaining myself well, my problem is that the information doesn't seem to be arriving/isn't being collected by the endpoint because always is null and i don't know why, 'ApellidoM' should always be required

Comment: So you are saying, when you are submitting the value from the client side the value you are getting in your controller for `ApellidoM` is always null? Does other value is coming accordingly?